# Access code behind members in radiobuttonlist inside gridview

Tags: asp.net

How can i access code behind methods from the radiobuttonlist insode the gridview below? Using code blocks is of some reason not allowed here..

`<asp:GridView ID="gvChildren" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblAccess">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="<%= Get("test")  %>"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<%= Get("test")  %>">dfgdfg</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="<%= Get("test")  %>"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible(Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event). You could set the Text in codebehind. 
For example:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblAccess">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Me.rblAccess.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rblAccess_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rblAccess.DataBound
    For Each item As ListItem In rblAccess.Items
        item.Text = getAccessText(item.Value)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function getAccessText(ByVal value As String) As String
    Return "text for item " & value
End Function
```